# Ayuda con Calculadora en Javascript y HTML , condicionales "IF" y "else if"

Tags: javascript, condiciones

Es una calculadora con un formularios de tres campos, 2 de texto (para llenar con caracteres númericos) y un "dropdown" o select o menú desplegable que contiene campos de texto.

La formula seria simplificada sería

**Resultado = campo de texto1* (campo de texto2 *(0.01+ 0.16 + "X"))**

Y allí es donde entran los condicionales porque el valor de esa "X" es un porcentaje llevado a decimal (obviamente) que varia o es determinado en base al valor del "input Type=select" o menú desplegable que son valores de texto.

En fin intenté resolverlo mediante este código pero no me arroja resultado, acá les dejo una muestra

```
<script>


function a (x,y,z) {

var x = parseFloat(x);
var y = parseFloat(y);

    if (z == "Telefonos") {return ( (x)*(( (y)*0.01)+( (y)*0.16)+( (y)*0.20)));
    }else if (z == "Televisores") {(return ( (x)*(( (y)*0.01)+( (y)*0.16)+( (y)*0.20)))); 
    } else if (z == "Equipos de computacion") {(return ( (x)*(( (y)*0.01)+( (y)*0.16)+( (y)*0.16)))); 
    } else if (z == "Camara de video") {(return ( (x)*(( (y)*0.01)+( (y)*0.16)+( (y)*0.05)))); 
    } else if (z == "Camara fotografica") {(return ( (x)*(( (y)*0.01)+( (y)*0.16)+( (y)*0.10)))); 
    } else if (z == "Electrodomesticos") {(return ( (x)*(( (y)*0.01)+( (y)*0.16)+( (y)*0.20)))); 
    } else if (z == "Ropa-Calzado") {(return ( (x)*(( (y)*0.01)+( (y)*0.16)+( (y)*0.20)))); 
    } else if (z == "Perfumes") {(return ( (x)*(( (y)*0.01)+( (y)*0.16)+( (y)*0.20)))); 
    } else if (z == "Libros") {(return ( (x)*(( (y)*0.01)+( (y)*0.16)+( (y)*0)))); 
    } else if (z == "Articulos deportivos") {(return ( (x)*(( (y)*0.01)+( (y)*0.16)+( (y)*0.20)))); 
    } else if (z == "Vitaminas") {(return ( (x)*(( (y)*0.01)+( (y)*0.16)+( (y)*0.05)))); 
    } else if (z == "Juguetes") {(return ( (x)*(( (y)*0.01)+( (y)*0.16)+( (y)*0.20)))); 
    } else if (z == "CDs.BlueRays") {(return ( (x)*(( (y)*0.01)+( (y)*0.16)+( (y)*0,15)))); 
    } else if (z == "Equipos de Sonido") {(return ( (x)*(( (y)*0.01)+( (y)*0.16)+( (y)*0.20))));  
        }else {
        alert("Ingresa alg&uacute;n valor"); 
}


</script>

<div class="form-mini-container">


            <h1>Mini Form</h1>

            <form class="form-mini" >

                <div class="form-row">
                    <input type="text" name="tasa" id="demo" >
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <input type="text" name="costo" placeholder="Your Email">
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                        <select name="tag" >
                            <option>Telefonos</option>
                            <option>Equipos de computacion</option>
                            <option>Televisores</option>
                            <option>Equipos de Sonido</option>
                            <option>Camara de video</option>
                            <option>Camara fotografica</option>
                            <option>Electrodomesticos</option>
                            <option>Ropa-Calzado</option>
                            <option>Perfumes</option>
                            <option>Libros</option>
                            <option>Articulos deportivos</option>
                            <option>Vitaminas</option>
                            <option>Juguetes</option>
                            <option>CDs-BlueRays</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </div>



                <div class="form-row">


                      <input type="text" name="result" >



                                    </div>

                <div class="form-row form-last-row">
                    <button type="submit" onclick="document.forms[0].result.value= a (document.forms[0].tasa.value,costo.value,tag.value);">Submit Form</button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: al momento de usar: if (z = "Telefonos") estás haciendo una asignanción a "z", cosa que no puedes en una condicional. debería ser (z == "Telefonos"), otra cosa parsea tus valores x,y,z antes de que entren en las condiciones y para tantas condicionales mejor usa una estructura switch.

Comment: Hice las modificaciones  (lo actualicé en el código de arriba) pero no me funciona todavia, tambien intenté una versión con switch pero no me arroja ningún resultado

Comment: el parseo de tus variables deben ser dentro de la función y no fuera.

Comment: cierto  ese error lo cometí copiando y pegando acá  pero sigue igual sin funcionar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solución:

```js
const inputTasa = document.getElementById('input-tasa')
const inputCosto = document.getElementById('input-costo')
const selectOption = document.getElementById('select-option')
const labelResult = document.getElementById('label-result')

function calcular() {
  let x = parseFloat(inputTasa.value)
  let y = parseFloat(inputCosto.value)

  let result = null
  let selectOptionValue = selectOption.value

  if (selectOptionValue == "Telefonos") {
    result = ((x) * (((y) * 0.01) + ((y) * 0.16) + ((y) * 0.20)));
  } else if (selectOptionValue == "Televisores") {
    result = ((x) * (((y) * 0.01) + ((y) * 0.16) + ((y) * 0.20)));
  } else if (selectOptionValue == "Equipos de computacion") {
    result = ((x) * (((y) * 0.01) + ((y) * 0.16) + ((y) * 0.16)));
  } else if (selectOptionValue == "Camara de video") {
    result = ((x) * (((y) * 0.01) + ((y) * 0.16) + ((y) * 0.05)));
  } else if (selectOptionValue == "Camara fotografica") {
    result = ((x) * (((y) * 0.01) + ((y) * 0.16) + ((y) * 0.10)));
  } else if (selectOptionValue == "Electrodomesticos") {
    result = ((x) * (((y) * 0.01) + ((y) * 0.16) + ((y) * 0.20)));
  } else if (selectOptionValue == "Ropa-Calzado") {
    result = ((x) * (((y) * 0.01) + ((y) * 0.16) + ((y) * 0.20)));
  } else if (selectOptionValue == "Perfumes") {
    result = ((x) * (((y) * 0.01) + ((y) * 0.16) + ((y) * 0.20)));
  } else if (selectOptionValue == "Libros") {
    result = ((x) * (((y) * 0.01) + ((y) * 0.16) + ((y) * 0)));
  } else if (selectOptionValue == "Articulos deportivos") {
    result = ((x) * (((y) * 0.01) + ((y) * 0.16) + ((y) * 0.20)));
  } else if (selectOptionValue == "Vitaminas") {
    result = ((x) * (((y) * 0.01) + ((y) * 0.16) + ((y) * 0.05)));
  } else if (selectOptionValue == "Juguetes") {
    result = ((x) * (((y) * 0.01) + ((y) * 0.16) + ((y) * 0.20)));
  } else if (selectOptionValue == "CDs.BlueRays") {
    result = ((x) * (((y) * 0.01) + ((y) * 0.16) + ((y) * 0, 15)));
  } else if (selectOptionValue == "Equipos de Sonido") {
    result = ((x) * (((y) * 0.01) + ((y) * 0.16) + ((y) * 0.20)));
  } else {
    // alert("Ingresa alg&uacute;n valor");
  }
  labelResult.innerHTML = result || ''
}
```

```html
<div class="form-mini-container">
    <h1>Mini Form</h1>
    <div class="form-mini">
        <div class="form-row">
            <input id="input-tasa" type="text" name="tasa">
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <input id="input-costo" type="text" name="costo" placeholder="Your Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <select id="select-option" name="tag">
                    <option>Telefonos</option>
                    <option>Equipos de computacion</option>
                    <option>Televisores</option>
                    <option>Equipos de Sonido</option>
                    <option>Camara de video</option>
                    <option>Camara fotografica</option>
                    <option>Electrodomesticos</option>
                    <option>Ropa-Calzado</option>
                    <option>Perfumes</option>
                    <option>Libros</option>
                    <option>Articulos deportivos</option>
                    <option>Vitaminas</option>
                    <option>Juguetes</option>
                    <option>CDs-BlueRays</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label id="label-result"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row form-last-row">
            <button onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

He refactorizado el html y script para una mejor legibilidad.

Recomendaciones:

- No necesitas un form para hacer el calculo que pretendes, ya que no
  dependes de un servidor para dicho calculo porque lo estás haciendo
  en JS.
- No se recomienda poner demasiada lógica o datos en el llamado de eventos desde las tags HTML, en tu caso le ponías a tu función a(...)
  muchos argumentos.
- El nombre de las funciones deben expresar la funcionalidad que resuelven, llamar a una función "a(...)", no expresa nada.
- En tu estructura if - else if, al ser tan extensa hace poco legible la implementación, cámbialo por una estructura switch.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, tomaré nota de tus recomendaciones pero el valor tasa en el original si es un valor dinamico y lo extraigo de un JSON de una URL alojada en un servidor de terceros, solo que omití el código porque distraia en solución del problema

Comment: Espero entonces puedas abstraer la lógica e implementarlo de acuerdo a tus necesidades.

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar el doble = para comparar valores dentro de los if, en tu codigo usas un solo =, ese es para asignar un valor,

```
z = 'a' // Se asigna el valor 'a' a la variable z
z == 'a' // Se compara el valor de z con 'a', devuelve true si es verdadero, false si es falso

if (z == "Telefonos") // Tus condicionales deben llevar ==
```

Comment: Lo hice pero me sigue sin dar resultado, (actualicé el código anterior)